# SQL Server Reporting Services: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, reporting-services, troubleshooting

I'm running a SharePoint 2010 Standard farm. I have 2 Web Front-end Servers, an application server running SSRS and 2 Database servers.

SSRS is installed using the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 RS Add-In for SharePoint.

There seems to be a problem with my SQL Server Reporting Services installation. When I try to manage the SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application via Central Administration > Manage Service Applications > SQL Server Reporting Services Service Application > System Settings or Manage Jobs, I receive the following error:

> **Error**
>   The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 4ee9d3bd-5db2-4268-a7c3-79d07e68449e
>
> Date and Time: 4/29/2013 1:58:40 PM

When trying to edit properties in Central Administration > General Application Settings > Set Server Defaults, I receive the following error:

> **Error**
>   An unexpected error occurred while connecting to the report server. Verify that the Reporting Services Service Application mapped
>   to this web application is available OR the report server is available
>   and configured for SharePoint Integrated mode.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 444eeb74-e9d3-420b-9afc-43cbef8ca1a3
>
> Date and Time: 4/29/2013 2:00:23 PM

Event Viewer shows the following Critical Error:

> Log Name:
>   Application Source: Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation
>   Date: 29/04/2013 14:00:55
>   Event ID: 6398 
>   Task Category: Timer 
>   Level: Critical
>   Keywords:
>   User:          ****_** 
>   Computer:      ***.***.**
>   Description: The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.Service.DoWorkTimerJob
>   (ID 2e51f6e0-7252-499f-a958-c41f5578c57e) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does
>   not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1).
>   If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported
>   method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response
>   were: '      IIS 7.5 Detailed
>   Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error    
>   
>       
>       6398
>       14
>       1
>       12
>       0
>       0x4000000000000000
>       
>       72145
>       
>       
>       Application
>       ***.***.**
>             
>       Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.SharedService.Service.DoWorkTimerJob
>       2e51f6e0-7252-499f-a958-c41f5578c57e
>       The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding
>   (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024
>   bytes of the response were: '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
>   XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">  <html
>   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  <head> 
>   <title>IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server
>   Error</title>  <style type="text/css">  <!-- 
>   body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background:#CBE1EF;}
>   code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
>   .config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
>   pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}  ul,ol{margin:10px
>   0 10px 40px;}  ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;}  fieldset{padding:0
>   15px 10px 15px;}  .summary-container
>   fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
>   legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
>   legend{color:#333333;padding:4px 15px 4px 10px;margin:4px 0 8px
>   -12px;_margin-top:0px;   border-top:1px solid #EDEDED;border-left:1px solid #EDEDED;border-right:1px solid #969696;   border-bottom:1px
>   solid #969696;background:#E7ECF0;font-weight:bold;'.

Any help in troubleshooting this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint-Reporting component must be installed from SQL 2012 SP1 on SharePoint 2013 
Have you not  you installed SQL2012 (and not SP1)?

See Supported Combinations
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492257.aspx

Comment: I have installed SP1 and re created service application. Still having same error. Can anyone help me on this?